# Convert A to SELECT upon Click Event with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using JQuery, and still a little new to it, trying to change an Link into a Drop Down of options, whi8ch the user can select from, and upon selecting a choice, it returns to a hyperlink with the text of the selection.

So far, I have:

```
$("a.timeChange").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $stamp = $(this).text();
    $.get("tstampoffsetter.php", { t: $stamp, a: 1 }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(this).replaceWith(data);
    });
});
$("#selectTimeStamp").change(function(){
    var i = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#'>" + i + "</a>");
});
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<a href='#' class='timeChange'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 04:20:45 -0700</a>
```

The data that is returned from the AJAX call is:

```
<select id="selectTimeStamp">
   <option value='1284445245'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 23:20:45 +1200</option>
   <option value='1284441645'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 22:20:45 +1100</option>
   <option value='1284438045'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 21:20:45 +1000</option>
   <option value='1284434445'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 20:20:45 +0900</option>
   <option value='1284430845'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 19:20:45 +0800</option>
   <option value='1284427245'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 18:20:45 +0700</option>
   <option value='1284423645'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 17:20:45 +0600</option>
   <option value='1284420045'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 16:20:45 +0500</option>
   <option value='1284416445'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 15:20:45 +0400</option>
   <option value='1284412845'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 14:20:45 +0300</option>
   <option value='1284409245'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 13:20:45 +0200</option>
   <option value='1284405645'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 12:20:45 +0100</option>
   <option value='1284402045'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 11:20:45 +0000</option>
   <option value='1284398445'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 10:20:45 -0100</option>
   <option value='1284394845'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 09:20:45 -0200</option>
   <option value='1284391245'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 08:20:45 -0300</option>
   <option value='1284387645'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 07:20:45 -0400</option>
   <option value='1284384045'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 06:20:45 -0500</option>
   <option value='1284380445'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 05:20:45 -0600</option>
   <option SELECTED value='1284376845'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 04:20:45 -0700</option>
   <option value='1284373245'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 03:20:45 -0800</option>
   <option value='1284369645'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 02:20:45 -0900</option>
   <option value='1284366045'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 01:20:45 -1000</option>
   <option value='1284362445'>Mon, 13 Sep 2010 00:20:45 -1100</option>
</select>
```

When the link is clicked, I get no error, yet the link does not become a drop down. I see the GET request via FireBug and it's returning the data, Status 200 OK 44ms. After I OK the Alert window, I see no change and no errors. Thanks for any help or advice you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `this` doesn't refer to the link in the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) success callback (it refers to the jQuery ajax object), you need to keep a reference to the anchor you clicked, like this:

```
$("a.timeChange").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this), $stamp = link.text();
    $.get("tstampoffsetter.php", { t: $stamp, a: 1 }, function(data){
       link.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
$("#selectTimeStamp").live("change", function(){
    var i = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='#' class='timeChange'>" + i + "</a>");
});
```

The `this` change fixes the first problem, as per your comment the second is binding to newly created elements you'll need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and when re-creating the link be sure it has the `timeChange` class (so the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) selector matches).

Comment: Thanks Nick! This fixed that first function. My second function is not applying to the new SELECT object. Do I need to attach that after I replace?

Comment: @Twisty - Oh, use `.live()` for that, e.g. `$("#selectTimeStamp").live("change", function(){` for the select, `$("a.timeChange").live("click", function(e){` for the anchor, I'll update in a moment.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect fix for that. Guffa beat you to it. All working just as I wanted.

Comment: @Twisty - Be careful, his solution and your original code doesn't add the `timeChange` class back, clicking the link again (created by the select going away) won't work :) Make sure to add the class back!

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Was scratching my head at why it was not working a second time. New code:

Comment: $("a.timeChange").live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this), $stamp = $(this).text();
  $.get("tstampoffsetter.php", { t: $stamp, a: 1 }, function(data){
   link.replaceWith(data);
  });
 });
 $("#selectTimeStamp").live('change', function(){
  //var i = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
  var selObj = $(this);
  selObj.replaceWith("<a href='#'>" + $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text() + "</a>");
 });

Comment: Copied the wrong version of the code: $("#selectTimeStamp").live('change', function(){
        var i = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
        var selObj = $(this);
        selObj.replaceWith("<a href='#' class='timeChange'>" + $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text() + "</a>");
    });

Comment: Any thoughts on reverting the event if the user clicks off the Select object? E.G User clicks on link, and then clicks on another section of the page.

Comment: @Twisty - Change `.live("change"` to `.live("change blur"` so it fires on both events.

Comment: No go with the following code: $("#selectTimeStamp").live('change blur', function(event){
        if(event.type == 'blur'){
            return false;
        }
        var i = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
        var selObj = $(this);
        selObj.replaceWith("<a href='#' class='timeChange'>" + $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text() + "</a>");
    });
--- Will keep poking at it, I think you gave me the right direction.

Comment: @Twisty - If you want to put the link back whenever clicking of the `<select>` I'd just remove that if check and `return false` portion.

Comment: @Nick - Tried it a few ways, just doesn't seem to catch the blur event: $("#selectTimeStamp").live('change blur', function(){
        var selObj = $(this);
        selObj.replaceWith("<a href='#' class='timeChange'>" + $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text() + "</a>");
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `live` method, so that the events will also be attached to elements that doesn't exist yet:

```
$("a.timeChange").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this)
    $.get("tstampoffsetter.php", { t: $link.text(), a: 1 }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        $link.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
$("#selectTimeStamp").live('change', function(){
    var text = $("#selectTimeStamp :selected").text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#">' + text + '</a>');
});
```

Comment: Guffa! You and Nick rocked it! Thanks, using .live() worked perfectly for the functions that would attach to the new Select Object.